# Reconstructing a Razor URL using referring URL and language selection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, localization, asp.net-mvc-routing, nullreferenceexception

To implement language selection in an MVC Razor application, I use a leading path segment in the route mapping like `www.mydomain.com/lang/controller/action/id?param=` where `lang` is a 2 letter ISO country code like fr, de, it, en etc

I use the following route mapping (which works fine):

```
// Special localisation route mapping - expects specific language/culture code as first param
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Localisation",
    url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { lang = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { lang = @"[a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2}" }
);
```

Previously I generated my language selection links in the master page, so that they were simply variations of the current URL (with only the first segment changed). Now I need to be able to create the links from within a partial view, that may be loaded dynamically via Ajax and the menu items (countries) are data driven.

That means I need to take the referring URL instead (the actual loaded page) and modify it to have a new language inserted, for each available language. The menu items are all database driven, so only contain the 2 letter language code and the display name.

Googling for *"how to separate a URL into controller and action"* I found an interesting link here: http://average-joe.info/url-to-route-data/

Based on that link, this is what I tried, but it blows up on a root URL like `http://localhost:51176/` or with a full URL like `http://localhost:51176/en/home/index`. I would have expected it to return the defaults of `home` (controller) and `index` (action). Instead I get a Null reference exception.

```
    string path = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
    string queryString = "";  // Blank for now
    System.Web.Routing.RouteData routeFromUrl = System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(new HttpContext(new HttpRequest(null, new UriBuilder(Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host, Request.Url.Port, path).ToString(), queryString), new HttpResponse(new System.IO.StringWriter()))));

    // Blows up with Null exception as routeFromUrl is always null
    string controller = (string)routeFromUrl.Values["controller"];
    string action = (string)routeFromUrl.Values["action"];
    string id = (string)routeFromUrl.Values["id"];
```

The idea being I can then generate links with href values like these using the referrers controller, action and parameters and therefore stay on the "same page" (except for the obvious language change):

```
http://localhost:51176/en/home/index
http://localhost:51176/de/home/index
http://localhost:51176/fr/home/index
```

What is wrong with the way I have used that piece of code (or does it just not work as I expected)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do'h... so simple.

Just needed to supply the path part of the URL *only* as it uses the current scheme, host & port applied to that path.

```
string path = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath;
```

### Also note (valuable tip):

If you follow that example I linked, like I did, you need to adjust the following to use `ToString()` as they do not cast to string *when empty*:

```
string controller = routeFromUrl.Values["controller"].ToString();
string action = routeFromUrl.Values["action"].ToString();
string id = routeFromUrl.Values["id"].ToString();
```

This will give `controller="home"`, `action="index"` and `id=""` as expected! Phew